# Overriding Public Initializers for URL

Tags: swift

I'd like to override a public initializer for a struct like URL. Currently the best implementation I can find is to define a similar initializer in a URL extension like so:

```
extension URL {

     init?(_ string: String) {

        if let url = URL(string: string) {
            self = url
            // insert additional code here
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

The negative is that I have to replace every instance of `URL(string: String)` in my application with `URL(string)`. I could swizzle the initializers, but that's not very Swift-friendly. The only other option would be to subclass URL, but that again means that I have to replace every instance of a URL in the app. Any other ideas?

*Note: I am doing this to keep track of every instances of an insecure `http` URL in my app, so that we can be prepared to make the switch over to `https` without missing any domains.*

Comment: `URL` is a `struct` – your cannot subclass it, or swizzle its methods.

Comment: This seems like a very bad idea. `URL` is a data holder, I cannot really imagine what functionality you would like to add there. Ideally, the best solution is to wrap anything in a custom function/methods. Yes, you will have to update the usage everywhere but that's the right thing to do.

Comment: If these are `http` URLs in your app, why doesn't searching the code for `http:` find them?

Comment: @RobNapier On larger projects URLs aren't always stored in the app. We have internal and external services/APIs that provide URLs for images or other data.

Comment: What you're trying to do with `URL` isn't possible, and is very fragile (there are lots of things it won't catch, such as URLs generated at other levels of the software). The better way to attack this problem is using a proxy like Charles (https://www.charlesproxy.com) or a sniffer like Wireshark to monitor all connections your app actually makes. I'd also look at bottlenecking your network access to a small number of objects that can perform logging for you. I'd also just check the URLs explicitly at the point that they come into the system (rather than every use).

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to override the initializer like you say. Since `URL` is a `struct`, you cannot subclass it. Even if you could, I wouldn't recommend it.

The initializer you added in an extension seems like a great solution.

```
extension URL {
   init?(_ string: String) { /*...*/ }
}
```